# saving coordinates from Dataframe as Polygons (shapely.geometry) AttributeError

Tags: python, dataframe, coordinates, polygon, shapely

I want to create a Polygon from a list of coordinates:

```
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon

data = pd.read_csv('path.csv', sep=';')
```

the data is in the following format

| Suburb | features_geometry_x | features_geometry_y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50.941840 | 6.9595637 |
| 1 | 50.941845 | 6.9595698 |
| 3 | 50.94182 | 6.9595632 |
| 4 | 50.9418837 | 6.9595958 |

with several rows for suburb 1, 3 and 4

```
#create a polygon


I = data.loc[data['Suburb'] == 1]
I['coordinates'] = list(zip(I['features_geometry_x'], I['features_geometry_y']))
poly_i = Polygon(I['coordinates'])
```

the code above works fine but if I do the same thing for suburb 3 and 4 it yields the following error:

```
L = data.loc[data['Suburb'] == 3]
L['coordinates'] = list(zip(L['features_geometry_x'], L['features_geometry_y']))
poly_l = Polygon(L['coordinates'])
```

File "shapely/speedups/_speedups.pyx", line 252, in shapely.speedups._speedups.geos_linearring_from_py

File "/Users/Jojo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5487, in **getattr**
return object.**getattribute**(self, name)

**AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute '**array_interface**'**

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/Users/Jojo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3361, in get_loc
return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)

File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 76, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 2131, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item

File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 2140, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item

**KeyError: 0**

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/var/folders/j6/wgg72kmx145f3krf14nzjfq40000gn/T/ipykernel_4092/214655495.py", line 3, in 
poly_l = Polygon(Lindenthal['coordinates'])

File "/Users/Jojo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shapely/geometry/polygon.py", line 261, in **init**
ret = geos_polygon_from_py(shell, holes)

File "/Users/Jojo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/shapely/geometry/polygon.py", line 539, in geos_polygon_from_py
ret = geos_linearring_from_py(shell)

File "shapely/speedups/_speedups.pyx", line 344, in shapely.speedups._speedups.geos_linearring_from_py

File "/Users/Jojo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 942, in **getitem**
return self._get_value(key)

File "/Users/Jojo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 1051, in _get_value
loc = self.index.get_loc(label)

File "/Users/Jojo/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 3363, in get_loc
raise KeyError(key) from err

**KeyError: 0**

Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you need more than one data  point to create a polygon where as your suburb 2 and 3 each got only a single point.

Comment: The OP says explicitly that the data has several rows for suburbs 1, 3 and 4.  And this should be a comment, not posted as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).